# Use arcpy.da.UpdateCursor in ArcGIS Pro to update a field with a NULL value

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I would like to search a specific field within an attribute table in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy and find all the null values and change the null value to the value above it. For example:

```
ID | field1 | field 2
0     23       40
1     30       <Null>
2     20       18
```

In the example above, I would like to convert the Null value to 40. Here is my attempt below:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ScaleRatioTable,['Area_sqmi_1'])as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[1]=='<Null>':
                    row[1]=row[0]
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I received the error that the "list index is out of range". I was wondering how I fix this code to make it run properly? I also don't understand the row[#]. Shouldn't the # be a variable?
e.g.

```py
n=0
n= n+1
if row[n] == None:
    row[n] = row [n-1]
```

Comment: Your example line of fields and values is a bit confusing, including me not seeing any NULL records.  Regarding ArcPy cursors, SQL NULL is converted to Python None.  What you are currently checking for is a string with the word '<NULL>', which isn't NULL.

Comment: ArcPy DA cursors are Pythonic -- NULL is `None`.  This likely a duplicate with at least one Question.

Comment: Note that the actual cause of the error is not the the issue presented in the title, but the fact that you didn't list both the source and destination columns in the fields list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the field value `is None` not `== '<Null>'` or `== None`.

Your 1st attempt also fails as the `row[n]` are the indexes of the *fields* in each row, not a link to the previous row. So if you create a cursor with `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ScaleRatioTable,['field1', 'field 2'])`, in every iteration of the `for row in cursor:` loop, `row[0]` is the value of `'field1'` and `row[1]` is the value of `'field2'`. And since you only asked for a single field, attempting to access `row[1]` raises an `IndexError` as `row` only has one element `row[0]`.

It seems like you want to replace Null values with the value of the previous row in the same field.  You would have to track the last non Null value yourself, e.g

```
last_non_null = None
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ScaleRatioTable,['field1']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] is None:
            row[0] = last_non_null
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            last_non_null = row[0]
```

**Note:** You have to define `last_non_null` before the loop and because there aren't any non null values *yet*, I initialised it as `None`.

The only time this will be an issue is if the first row/s is `None` .   You can however initialise the `last_non_null` variable as whatever you want.  If you want a default value of 0 for the first N rows that don't have a value preceeding them, go for it.

e.g. Given:

```
ID | field N
0    <Null>
1    <Null>
2    40
3    <Null>
4    18
5    <Null>
6    <Null>
```

Output if `last_non_null` is initialised as `None`:

```
ID | field N
0    <Null>
1    <Null>
2    40
3    40
4    18
5    18
6    18
```

Output if `last_non_null` is initialised as `0`:

```
ID | field N
0    0
1    0
2    40
3    40
4    18
5    18
6    18
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to loop through one field and replace all the rows with null values (None) with the value of the row above it, which is not a null value. In your example, if the row value is None, then it will equal the last non-null value, which makes sense, but why does the last non-null value = None? It should have a value to replace the null value. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GIS_developer does this now answer your question?